# Sleep method locks my GUI

Tags: java

What I want to do is to make some part of the code in a class of my programm to wait for sometime, but my problem is that the way I am trying to it makes my GUI to stuck. I mean, pressing a button i make my program to wait for sometime, while my program is waiting i press a button, the button is pressed but after that if i try to press any other button while the program is still waiting i can't, the first button i pressed seems to be pressed and the other button can't be pressed although the program does what I want to do(accepts all the commands) the only problem is that my GUI is locked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use multiple threads.  Any "work" that needs to be done that may take any significant / noticeable amount of time needs to be done in its own thread.  (This certainly includes any code where you are calling `sleep`.)

Here are 3 good references:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/
- http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads1.html
- http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Threads/swing/

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I am actually condused, I have to read these stuff. I suppose that if I use the the Thread.sleep my GUI stucks because I make the AWT-EventQueue-0 to wait, right? Also if I use the join for another thread i have created i am making the the current thread(which obviously is the AWT-EventQueue-0) to wait for my thread to finish, so it is the same thing. I finally put a thread in a specified method and it works as i want, but any further explanation would be great help! Thank you!

Comment: @anna - you're correct with your other assumptions listed here.

Answer (score 1):

For the parts you are doing sleep and after when the first button pressed, you can try this:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        //and whatever you need to do
    }
});
```

If you need to use any local variables in the button pressed method, they need to be the final variables.

Comment: This would put the EDT to sleep and make the GUI unresponsive for 5 seconds.

Comment: Yes, this is just an example of what Anna described in the problem. Her code has something to stop the following execution for some time.
"pressing a button i make my program to wait for sometime"

Putting it in a separate Runnable/Thread can stop the GUI hanging. That's why I am using invokeLater. 
Of course she should replace the sleep with her actual code.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide any code so it's impossible to give direct input on your code.  If you're using Swing and need to perform time-consuming processing, use a Swing Worker thread.  Here is a tutorial on using the `SwingWorker` class:

[Using a Swing Worker Thread](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads2.html)

Answer (score -1):

Your GUI is loaded and runs on one thread, your wait function runs on the same thread, thereby locking up the GUI. You need to start the wait function on a separate thread.

Comment: the java gui does not run on the main thread, it runs on the awt event thread. However all gui actions/listeners are executed on that thread as well.