# Computer Vs Computer Loop Java Applet

Tags: java, applet, awt, delay, event-dispatch-thread

I am having issues setting up a computer vs computer loop in my java game applet. I have been trying for 3 days now to effectively add a one second delay between the two computer-player turns, while also repainting the board. I have tried try/catch/thread.sleep and wait and a few other tricks, however none have been successful. In the program's current state, when a computer vs computer game is initiated, the program freezes for the duration of the game (with one second delays between moves) and then displays the final board when the game has finished. How can I make it so the program repaints/delays after each move? From all of the reading I have done, **I am aware that the following implementation will not work** but my issue is I cannot figure out how to do it any other way.
Thanks in advance!

The following code is inside my actionPerformed listener method

```
if (event.getSource() == startAIvAI)
    {
        drawing.clear();

        while (drawing.hasWon() == -1 && !drawing.isFull())
        {

            go1();
            repaint();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {}

            go2();
            repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {}

        }


    }
```

Comment: 1) Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix. 2) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). ..

Comment: .. 3) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free). 4) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

When you invoke `Thread.sleep(1000);` which Thread do you think you're pausing? Probable the one handling event given your code start with `if (event.getSource() == startAIvAI)`.

You should read this to understand what to do: [Sleep method locks my GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8682692/sleep-method-locks-my-gui)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but that didn't help me. I just tried two implementations using that SwingUtilities invoke later stuff and again, just froze up the gui for the length of the game